# Image Editor - My image representation blinks

Tags: c#, .net, image

I'm working on an `image editor` (it's really like a hobby) and I'm having a little problem with the visual representation of the image and changes.

The project follows the `MVC design pattern`, (the project is in fact a little more complicated that a simple image editor but this is not what matters) and for the editing I use a `board` ("pixel's" matrix) as the model part and a modified `view panel` (its responsibility is to make the visual representation of the state of the board)

When I modified the `board` (for example, painting one pixel with a pen) I `invalidate` the panel and it has to fully repaint itself. (I suppose given the fact that a PC automatics refresh (repaint) itself several times per seconds the CPU will not mind to repaint the entire panel each time I modify just one pixel)

The problem is that the image blinks, and if I move my **pen fast** , you don't see a line, you see a `dashed line`.

The complexity of my "repainting" algorithm is `O(n^2)`.

I tried with different styles, likes double buffered and opaque...

Anyone can suggest me a better algorithm or a better dessign pattern that I can use in order to fix this problem...

Comment: you need to show us your code!

Comment: I don't have the code right here, is a shared project (and we don't have svn yet).
I'm publishing the question as a favor to my friend who doesn't have Internet...

Comment: about the code: When a pixel is changed, I invalidate the panel, the painting method repaint the entire panel by looking for the values of each pixel in the board. I change a pixel every time the user move the mouse (with the left button pressed) above one pixel.

The code itself, is not the problem, the problem is the method used, every time I change the value of a pixel I repaint the entire panel, something tell me that the panel is being modificated more that 10^8 times per second, that logically is more than my machine can do